# How would I properly change the style of an element in React, without having it constantly change as I update state?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My question is a bit ambiguous, mostly because I am having a tough time putting the right words together to ask a more precise question. However, I think my example should make it quite clear.

I am making a todo list with React, and when I add a todo to the list, it also has an inline marker color to make it look a bit more 'aesthetic'. I want this color to be one of the random colors I have stored in an array.

My CodePen here shows an example of what's happening in my result; once I add a task with a marker color, when adding a second task, upon the `onChange` attribute on the input, my todo colors start to change due to the state being changed, and React re-rendering the component (at least, that's what I think is happening). How can I prevent this, and have one random color stored in each todo task?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/webdevpchoi/pen/Mzvdpq?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the color when you add the Todo to the state and put the color into the state, for example on the Todo object itself.

For example, in `addHandler`:

```
const currentTodo = this.state.currentTodo;
const markerColors = ['#F8C8C8', '#C0F5E6', '#C5C5F9', '#F5EFC0'];
currentTodo.color = markerColors[getRandomInt(0, markerColors.length)];
```

And remove that code from the `createList` function, leaving only

```
const colorObj = {
  background: todo.color,
}
```

I modified your codepen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xQjpOv?editors=0010